# Range check and Length check in Ada (SPARK Mode)

Tags: ada, formal-verification

these last weeks I have been trying to learn the ADA language, to do it I made an exercise to reverse a string using recursion, however when I compile it with GNATProve it gives me several errors which I have not been able to solve, it would be of great help if you could guide me on how to solve them using Preconditions and Postconditions.

My code:

```
function String_Reverse(Str:String) return String with
        Pre => Str'Length > 0 ,
        Post => String_Reverse'Result'Length <= Str'Length;
        function String_Reverse (Str : String) return String is
            Result : String (Str'Range);
        begin
            if Str'Length = 1 then
                Result := Str;
            else
                Result :=
                   String_Reverse (Str (Str'First + 1 .. Str'Last)) &
                   Str (Str'First);
         end if;
            return Result;
        end String_Reverse;
```

Errors:

```bash
dth113.adb:18:69: low: range check might fail
   18>|                   String_Reverse (Str (Str'First + 1 .. Str'Last)) &
   19 |                   Str (Str'First);
  reason for check: result of concatenation must fit in the target type of the assignment
  possible fix: precondition of subprogram at line 8 should mention Str
    8 |      function String_Reverse(Str:String) return String with
      |      ^ here
dth113.adb:18:69: medium: length check might fail
   18>|                   String_Reverse (Str (Str'First + 1 .. Str'Last)) &
   19 |                   Str (Str'First);
  reason for check: array must be of the appropriate length
  possible fix: precondition of subprogram at line 8 should mention Str
    8 |      function String_Reverse(Str:String) return String with
      |      ^ here
```

I'm tried using Preconditons and Postconditions about the input Str length

Comment: Shouldn’t the result’s length be the same as that of the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnatprove appears to have some difficulty with concatenating arrays.

This below proves, using subtypes rather than pre- and post-conditions. Proving that the result is actually the reverse of the input string might be trickier!

Spec:

```ada
pragma SPARK_Mode;
function String_Reverse (Str : String) return String with
  Pre => Str'Length > 0,
  Post => String_Reverse'Result'Length = Str'Length;
```

Body:

```ada
pragma SPARK_Mode;
function String_Reverse (Str : String) return String is
   subtype Result_String is String (Str'Range);
   Result : Result_String;
begin
   if Str'Length = 1 then
      Result := Str;
   else
      declare
         subtype Part_String is String (1 .. Str'Length - 1);
         Reversed_Part : constant Part_String
           := String_Reverse (Str (Str'First + 1 .. Str'Last));
      begin
         Result := Reversed_Part & Str (Str'First);
      end;
   end if;
   return Result;
end String_Reverse;
```

---

With a minor change you could handle zero-length strings as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon! I see that there is a long way to go to learn about this language. Your answer helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Your program keeps appending the bulk of the string to your result. This makes a string much larger than the initial string parameter. You cannot fix this with improved preconditions or post conditions.

See the difference between your solution and the Reverse_String function shown below. In the solution below the size of the returned string cannot be the size of the function string in parameter because it is building the reversed string with each recursion and the size of the string cannot be determined until all recursions complete.

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
   function Reverse_String(S : in String; Idx : Positive) return String is
   begin
      if Idx < S'Last then
         return Reverse_String(S, Idx + 1) & S(Idx);
      else
         return S(Idx) & "";
      end if;
   end Reverse_String;

   S1 : String := "Hello World";
   s2 : String := "1234567890";
   N1 : Integer := 12345;
   N3 : Integer;
begin
   Put_Line(S1 & " : " & Reverse_String(S1, 1));
   Put_Line(S2 & " : " & Reverse_String(S2, 1));
   N3 := Integer'Value(Reverse_String(N1'Image, 1));
   Put_Line(N1'Image & " : " & N3'Image);
end Main;
```

This version of Reverse_String keeps incrementing the index of the input string and concatenating that character at the end of all the characters yet to reverse.
The Reverse_String's else clause appends an empty string to the last character so that it is viewed by the compiler as a string and not a character because S(Idx) is a single character and is not a string, but concatenating S(Idx) with an empty string results in a string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another implementation

```
function String_Reverse (Str : String) return String is
    Result : String (Str'Range) := Str;
begin       
    for I in reverse Str'Range loop
        Result(Str'Last - I + Result'First) := Str(I);
    end loop;
    return Result;
end String_Reverse;
```

Comment: Doesn’t use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

SPARK seems to be happier with expression functions than with regular functions in many cases. I don't know if it will make a difference, but you could try rewriting the body of your function as

```
function String_Reverse (Str : String) return String is
   (if Str'Length = 1 then
       Str
    else
       String_Reverse (Str (Str'First + 1 .. Str'Last) ) & Str (Str'First) );
```

(I hope I've got the parentheses balanced.)

Typically one allows null strings, and the function becomes something like

```
function Reversed (S : in String) return String with
   Post => Reversed'Result'Length = S'Length;

function Reversed (S : in String) return String is
   (if S'Length = 0 then ""
    else Reversed (S (S'first + 1 .. S'Last) & S (S'First) );
```

(Hint: "Ada" is a woman's name, not an acronym. GNATProve is a static-analysis tool, not a compiler.)